# "this apk file might contain unsafe content" issue

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I have succesfully made an APK app with python kivy using buildozer. I load it to my phone with cable connection. I give permissions on my phone to install it and it is working.

However, I cant send the apk file by whatsapp, gmail, even yandex mail. Other android phones that I have send dont accept to install it because it seems unsafe. Because of the same reason I cant send it in other platforms just as I have tolled.

It is the message when they try to install it;

[image]

How can I make my apk app legitimate for all platforms ?

I want my clients recieve the apk app and install it without giving any permission in their phone.

Comment: "How can I make my apk app legitimate for all platforms ?" upload it to google play... many phones are set-up to only use apk files from google play by default, and require entering developer mode in order to install apk files downloaded elsewhere.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support. This isn't a question about how to write code; it's a question about how to comply with security restrictions on the hardware. Please try https://superuser.com ; it's off topic here.

Comment: @Aaron It doesn't require developer mode, but it does require checking the "Allow unsafe sources" setting.  Which is a little less work, but still off by default on every device I know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way.  That message is going to pop up on any device, because its a generic warning that you're trying to install an executable.  It's meant to make sure the user wants to do it before they do.